# Animate with position and orientation from txt file

Tags: python, animation, import

I want to animate a body using an external file with **x, y, z coordinates** and **quaternion data**.

In the file every entry `[x,y,x,q0,q1,q2,q3]` represents a frame to be rendered.

I heard about Blender and its compatibility with python and, since I am a python user, I would like to know if it is possible to do what I mentioned above and how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very possible, and doesn't even sound difficult to do.

Make sure `Object.rotation_mode` is `'QUATERNION'` (once for the object):

```
ob = bpy.context.object # active object, assuming there is one
ob.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
```

Reading the file:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Quaternion

file = open("input.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    x, y, z, q0, q1, q2, q3 = line.strip(" \t\r\n[]").split(",")
    loc = float(x), float(y), float(z)
    quat = float(q0), float(q1), float(q2), float(q3)

    # Or cast to Vector / Quaternion type if you need any methods of them later
    #loc = Vector(loc)
    #quat = Quaternion(quat)
```

I assume line 1 in the file is meant to be the first frame in Blender and so on. Let's keep track of the line number:

```
for i, line in enumerate(file, 1):
    ...
```

Assign the location and the rotation in our for-loop:

```
    ob.location = loc
    ob.rotation_quaternion = quat
```

and insert keyframes for frame `i`:

```
    ob.keyframe_insert('location', frame=i)
    ob.keyframe_insert('rotation_quaternion', frame=i)
```

Finally, we close the file:

```
file.close()
```

For a better performaning way to animate with python, see:

http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/info_quickstart.html#animation

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works! I just want to add something: loc and quat can't have string entries so they must be transform to float.

Comment: Geez! Totally forgot to cast to numbers, edited my post. `float()` accepts any kind of floating point notation: `0.1`, `.1`, `1.`, `1e-3`. For integer values, you would use `int()` (no rounding if used on floats, use `math.round()` instead if needed). Properties like `Object.location` accept several types without explicit casting, Vector, int, float...