# Keyframing with Python

Tags: python, keyframes

I'm working in a project school. I have created an app, that takes information of the accelerometer and the gyroscope from my mobile while I am moving it. This app generates a .txt, with all the values of both of them.
The text file shows the x,y,z values of the accelerometer and x,y,z values of the gyroscope of the specific movement that the app recorded from the mobile. It is like this:
ACELERÒMETRE:((()) -x1,z1,y1- -x2,y2,z2- -x3,y3,z3-....... -------GIROSCOPI:(--x1,z1,y1- -x2,y2,z2- -x3,y3,z3.....

The question is, how I could send this values to the blender. I have tried to do it with the python console of the Blender, but I have no idea to do it.
[The link for one of the files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NWJF6FsA9wQmF6bVBuT01XZUV2VFdoRE5vWEFCdUE2Nl93)

Comment: In realtime? Otherwise see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24229/31447

Comment: No, I only want to put the results of the file in the "ROTATION" and "LOCATION" values of Blender in each frame.

Comment: Ok, that's easy. Please share a simplified version of your text file containing some values to play with, also see my [answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80230/how-to-make-blender-use-text-file-as-an-input-of-bones-animation/80466#80466).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Here is a simplified file: [.txt file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NWJF6FsA9wbW9TS3BNZ2NFWF9STHNXMEJkbEFwWU55cW5z)